# How to fix npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled

Tags: node.js

I want update Node.js on my device via the terminal. But when ever I input the code , it gives me a "Recommended protections disabled" error message. How do I solve the problem? Below is an attached picture of the error message.[a WARN recommended protections disabled errror message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp35E.png)

Comment: Well, don't use `-f` (`--force`) and it won't warn about that.

Comment: #Please post the code or error into your question, not an image. So that users can replicate the issue.